# Reverse array with for loop in Java

Tags: java, arrays, reverse

I was wondering if you can help me around this code. It should reverse content of array but I get this. Does anyone know how to fix this?

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Arrays7 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Write a Java program to reverse an array of integer values.
        
        int arr[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
        int petlja[] = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };       
        
         /* arr[0] = petlja[4];
        arr[1] = petlja[3];
        arr[2] = petlja[2];
        arr[3] = petlja[1];
        arr[4] = petlja[0];
        */
        
        for ( int i=4; i>0; i--) {
            for ( int j=0; j<4; j++) {
                petlja[j] = arr[i];
            }
        }
        
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(petlja));
```

Comment: I think you're just guessing, which doesn't help you learn.  Write down the steps to do this by hand.  Then try to duplicate those steps on the computer.  Hint: you only need one loop, not two nested loops.

Comment: If you still aren't able to figure out, Swap the first and the last element of the array and write down how the computer will execute it and according set the condition.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a nested loop - you need only one loop to go over the array and assign each element to the corresponding "reversed" array:

```java
for (int i = arr.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    petlja[petlja.length - i] = arr[i];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like so:

```
    for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        petlja[i] = arr[array.length-i-1];
    }
```

**Sample I/O**

*Input*

```
1, 2, 3, 4, 5
```

*Output*

```
5, 4, 3, 2, 1
```